# How can I get the number of rows in a MySQL table with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Why is my code returning a 500 Internal Server error on the line `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM institutions");` Am I doing something horrifically wrong? All I am trying to do is count the number of rows in a MySQL table (called 'institutions') after I have just added a row to that table.

```
    $institution_sql = "
    INSERT INTO `institutions`
    (`InstitutionName`, `HeaderPictureID`, `Description`, `DevicesInfo`, `DoingInfo`, `FacebookPage`, `Location`, `TwitterHandle`, `Website`, `CreatedAt`)
    VALUES
    (" . nz($_POST['TempInstitutionName']) . ", 74, 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'On the Internet', 'N/A', 'N/A', NOW())
    ";

    $mysqli->query($institution_sql);
    if ($mysqli->errno) {
        $dbreturn['status'] = "PASSWORD_FAILURE";
    } else {
        $dbreturn['status'] = "EXEC_SUCCESS";

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM institutions");
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        echo "There are " . $rows . " rows in my table.";

        $insert_sql = "
        INSERT INTO `users`
        (`Handle`, `Email`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `InstitutionID`, `TempInstitutionName`, `TwitterHandle`, `ProfilePictureID`, `HeaderPictureID`, `AccountType`, `CreatedAt`)
        VALUES
        (" . nz($_POST['Handle']) . ", " . nz($_POST['Email']) . ", " . nz($_POST['FirstName']) . ", " . nz($_POST['LastName']) . ", $num_rows, " . nz($_POST['TempInstitutionName']) . ", " . nz($_POST['TwitterHandle']) . ", " . nz('75') . ", " . nz('74') . ", " . nz($_POST['AccountType']) . ",NOW())
        ";

        $mysqli->query($insert_sql);
        if ($mysqli->errno) {
            $dbreturn['status'] = "EXEC_FAILURE";
        } else {
        $dbreturn['status'] = "EXEC_SUCCESS";

        $insertid = $mysqli->insert_id;

        $password_sql = "
        INSERT INTO `passwords`
        (`UserID`)
        VALUES
        ('$insertid')
        ";

        $mysqli->query($password_sql);
        if ($mysqli->errno) {
            $dbreturn['status'] = "PASSWORD_FAILURE";
        } else {
            $dbreturn['status'] = "EXEC_SUCCESS";
        }

        } //todo: use a transaction here

    }
```

Comment: Try using `count(*)`instead of * if you want the count of rows. You really dont want to getting all the data in your entire table unncessarily

Comment: or even `count(1)`, though I think MySQL is probably pretty smart about that these days

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM institutions;`

Answer (score 2):

$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM institutions");

This will directly return the number of rows.

This link can detail you

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

Answer (score 2):

your problem is that you mixing `MYSQLI` with `MYSQL`

rewrite your code using mysqli

```
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM institutions");
    $rows = $result->num_rows ;
  //  and so on ...
```

you are connecting via mysqli and then you use mysql in your code.

Comment: really downvote ? isnt he mixing mysqli with mysql ? downvoter can explain why ?

Comment: +1 echo_Me. OP is mixing both mysqli and mysql. Even if it isn't the cause, it's still an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$result = $mysqli->query($institution_sql);
$result->num_rows;
```

Or for plain old mysql

```
$result = mysql_query($institution_sql);
mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM institutions");
```

MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Also this:  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

```
SQL COUNT(*) Syntax
```

The COUNT(*) function returns the number of records in a table:

Answer (score 0):

...also, that should be:

VALUES
    ('" . nz($_POST['TempInstitutionName']) . "', 74

Note the single quotes [unless the 'nz' function takes care of that].